# Harbor Invalid user name or password in port forward

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, portforwarding, harbor

I am unable to login to harbor portal after installing it in kubernetes and port forwarding it. Harbor-core service is not accessible and I am not sure if I should accesss harbor core or harbor portal. When i port forward harbor portal, it never logins even with the credentials provided in the values.yml file. What am I doing wrong? I have tried different browsers and incognito as well. There should be no ambiguity regarding external url and exposing because I am trying to first access it locally with port forwarding and even then, it is not authenticating.

I have already tried all the solutions provided online such as removing quotes from password field in values.yaml and enable/disable tls/https etc nothing is working.[image]

Comment: You cant do that . Harbor is a container registry. It needs to be able to do docker login. Please set the externalURL in values.yaml to your domain and also set the ingress. Make sure the TLS of the domain is configured properly.

Comment: This is something to do after I am atleast able to login the harbor portal page. I am running it in kubernetes with port forwarding to first check even if it would login. There are a number of other people who have the same issue on internet that harbor portal does not accept the password.

Comment: When it doesnt work whith what i said earlier check the logs of harbor-core because login logs will be displayed there. Also a good Idea is to turn the log level to debug. Hope it helps :)

Comment: This worked only after setting up externalURL. Thanks